# qsub passing parameters to -N (name) option

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, qsub

I'm submitting a bunch of qsub jobs that take a range of parameter values. I run the following loop to submit these multiple jobs. I pass the specific parameter values to qsub through -v. I would like the jobname to also be a function of these parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for a in 1 2
do
  for b in 1 2
  do
  echo "a is $a, b is $b"
      qsub -v a=$a,b=$b -N run_$a_$b run_file.sh
  done
done
```

Where the run_file.sh contains the #PBS commands to run the program.
When I submit to the server I see the following output that shows the loop is working correctly:

```
a is 1, b is 2
```

But the job name appears only with the last parameter

```
run_$b (i.e. run_2 for $b=2)
```

Instead of as

```
run_$a_$b
```

How can I get the jobname to include both parameters? I have tried shortening the file name to confirm it's not a length issue. I would like the name to appear with both parameters to keep track of which files are still running without needing to check the output files. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really run this script but try:
qsub -v a=$a,b=$b -N run_${a}_${b} run_file.sh

hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: yes, that works - both parameters now appear (so do the braces, but that is ok). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in run_$a_$b bash consider $a_ as one variable and apparently you do not have a_ defined
something like this should work?
run_${a}_$b